# SSRS:Use decimal place in expression

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to minimize the decimal place in my report.

my expression:

```
="On: "& Avg(Fields!System.Value) & " OFF: " & avg(Sum(Fields!A1.Value)/Sum(Fields!A2.Value)*100)
```

[image]

I would like to show no decimal place for ON and one deciaml place for OFF.
I tried it with the function of ssrs but that is not possible.
How can I do this in this expression?

Comment: What function did you try? `Format( )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
="On: "& FORMAT(Avg(Fields!System.Value),"N2") & " OFF: " & FORMAT(avg(Sum(Fields!A1.Value)/Sum(Fields!A2.Value)*100),"N2")
```

In `"Nx"` replace `x` by the number of decimals you want to show.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Do you know how I can replace "On" and "OFF" in Bold?

Comment: @M.JAY, check [this](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/10/31/using-different-formats-within-a-single-textbox-in-ssrs.html)